# Как создавать статические библиотеки C++, включающие в себя другие библиотеки статически?

Tags: c++, библиотеки, линковка

Например, я написал обёртку для работы с OpenSSL, и хочу сделать из этого кода статическую библиотеку, но так, чтобы в линкере использующих её проэктов дописывать только `-lmycryptowrap`, вместо `-lcrypto -lssl -lmycryptowrap`.

Какие инструменты из наборов MinGW или GNU для этого используются и с какими флагами/аргументами?

Comment: Если `crypto` и `ssl` тоже статические, то разберите их на .o с помощью `ar`, и добавтье эти .o в свою `mycryptowrap`

Comment: @avp, хорошо, а как это делается? )

Comment: [man ar](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar)

Comment: Так обычно не делают. Писать полный список библиотек - нормально. (Особенно если делать это не вручную, а каким-нибудь `pkg-config`.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, знаю, просто хочется поэкспериментировать )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Библиотеки **libcrypto.a** и **libssl.a** по факту являются архивами **ar** хранящий в себе объектные файлы, для распаковки достаточно выполнить

```
ar -x libexample.a
```

После чего достаточно их закинуть туда же где хранятся obj фалы Вашей библиотеки(возможно распакованной таким же образом) и запаковать их обратно с помощью

```
ar rcs libout.a out1.o out2.o *.o
```